# Android reports my application is incompactible with my devices

Tags: google-play

Good day.
I have devices philips Xenium W732 (android 4.0.3)  and Lenovo VIBE p1n (android 5.0) .
I published my application in  google play.
 AndroidManifest.xml of my application is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.thetheory.losscalculator"
   android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="ru.thetheory.losscalculator.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Google play reports, that both my devices are incompactible ,thought I tested application  on on the both of them.
I tryied to download the application the same  google account, I published it . 
Is it allowed to recieve own applications  in google play , or developer account and google play account must be different google accounts, in order device was reported, to be  compactible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question.
I answer it.
My problem was not in application at all.
My application is published , as  not free application.
If application is not free, google play does not allow to download it , if developer account and google play account  are the same.
It is google play policy.
The WEB interface of google play does not show correct error mesage. 
In this case, google play WEB just show error message (your devices are incompactible).
But if you try to buy it  from the phone , you recieve real error message.